# mv: cannot stat 'pencil.desktop': No such file or directory

Tags: apt, evolus-pencil

I have been trying to install the [Pencil Project](https://pencil.evolus.vn/Downloads.html) on `Ubuntu-18.04` to design user interfaces before implementing it. 
I have been having the following installation problem and I am not sure why. After downloading it I only

```
sudo apt install ./pencil_3.1.0.ga_amd64.deb && sudo apt install -f
```

Below the warning:

> emanuele@pc:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i
>   pencil_3.1.0.ga_amd64.deb && sudo apt install -f (Reading database ...
>   257381 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
>   pencil_3.1.0.ga_amd64.deb ... Unpacking pencil (3.1.0.ga) over
>   (3.1.0.ga) ... rm: cannot remove
>   '/usr/share/applications/pencil.desktop': No such file or directory
>   rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/applications/pencil.png': No such file
>   or directory Setting up pencil (3.1.0.ga) ... mv: cannot stat
>   'pencil.desktop': No such file or directory mv: cannot stat
>   'pencil.png': No such file or directory chmod: cannot access
>   '/usr/share/applications/pencil.*': No such file or directory Reading
>   package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state
>   information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 529
>   not upgraded.

And I am not sure why is not being installed.
I consulted [this source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77007/mv-cannot-stat-no-such-file-or-directory-in-shell-script) and also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164497/mv-cannot-stat-with) and both sources said that there is a missing file in the folder indicated in the warning. There seems to be a missing icon or `.png`. But I downloaded the `.deb` from the [official documentation](https://pencil.evolus.vn/Downloads.html). and simply

```
 sudo apt install ./pencil_3.1.0.ga_amd64.deb && sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: Though "official", it's the worst packaging examples seen in a very long time. Please also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218294/mv-cannot-stat-pencil-desktop-no-such-file-or-directory/1218335#1218335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is neat, let me tell you what I think is happening

```
Unpacking pencil (3.1.0.ga) over (3.1.0.ga)
```

You installed 3.1.0.ga, and are now reinstalling (it should be fine to reinstall packages)

```
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/applications/pencil.desktop': No such file or directory 
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/applications/pencil.png No such file or directory
```

It is trying to uninstall it self, from the first install. (The first install did not put these file here, so they can't be found the uninstall)

```
Setting up pencil (3.1.0.ga)
```

It is starting the install

```
mv: cannot stat 'pencil.desktop': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'pencil.png': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/usr/share/applications/pencil.*': No such file or directory
```

These three lines are the root of your issue. I downloaded the package, and the files are all present, but I assume it is a path issue.

So, lets look at the script that is not able to move the files correctly. It is called postinst, and it is a shell script

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME=pencil
VERSION=3.1.0.ga
EXECUTABLE=pencil

mkdir -p /opt/$NAME-$VERSION

APP_PATH=/usr/share/applications

cd /opt/$NAME-$VERSION
mv $NAME.desktop $APP_PATH/
mv $NAME.png $APP_PATH/
chmod 644 /usr/share/applications/$EXECUTABLE.*

cd /usr/bin

if [ -L $EXECUTABLE ]; then
    rm $EXECUTABLE
fi

ln -s /opt/$NAME-$VERSION/$EXECUTABLE $EXECUTABLE

#cd /opt/$NAME-$VERSION
```

The two mv (move files) that don't work, and and the chmod (change permissions) are clearly there.

Probably, (and I don't know for sure) but I think the step before this script runs, files get moved to /opt/$NAME-$VERSION/ (opt/pencil/3.1.0.ga/ ), and for reasons I don't understand that is not happening.

The owners of this project know there are some issues with the installer (https://github.com/evolus/pencil/issues/520) , and it might not be the most stable tool to work with, if you are new to programming/linux.

This user has a similar issue
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1172077/pencil-does-not-install-on-ubuntu-18-04

If you are determined to use this software, it looks as if the other users are building from the source files. (this is typically more error prone, but very standard for software developers). Let us know if you have more questions, or if plan to build from source.

Comment: I ran  sudo apt install ./pencil_3.1.0.ga_amd64.deb  and it worked just fine for me. I am running 4.9.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.189-3+deb9u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: can you try to type "pencil" no quotes on the command line? and see if the program launches. You don't need the icon, or the .desktop

Comment: Thanks your explanation was very detailed and thanks also for the script. I managed to have it working using the nightly build from the official documentation.

Comment: @Johnb answer worked for me. If the GUI is not starting just reboot your OS. Is there a better software than pencil?

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same issue with that same version. When I tried to install with:

```
apt install ./pencil_3.1.0.ga_amd64.deb && sudo apt install -f
```

It threw me the same error, but then I uninstalled it before with the -f option

```
apt-get remove -f pencil
```

And then, again

```
apt install ./pencil_3.1.0.ga_amd64.deb && sudo apt install -f
```

That's what I did, and that worked

PD:
I would to point out, that, if after install it fails to startup, you can try to search with gnome-system-monitor or htop all pencil processes and kill/terminate. It is also what happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem with pencil_3.1.0.ga_amd64.deb file. When I run the following two lines as sudo, it was possible for me to install successfully. First line is for removing wrongly installed files in case of corrupted installation(this may fail, try to run the second line anyway), second line is for installation and fixing broken dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get remove -f pencil
sudo apt install ./pencil_3.1.0.ga_amd64.deb && sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: good to point out for the ```sudo apt install -f``` what the ```-f```` actually does, ie 'Fix. Attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place'

Comment: Thanks, good point! I added your comment as well